# Keeping devices secure on a WIFI network

Tags: malware, attacks

I am using a public WIFI network before work how do i keep my devices secure on this network?
I am looking to prevent a attacker using a packet sniffer to grab my data and i am looking to prevent malware from infecting my devices. 
Note: I am not asking only how to secure my data during transmission i am also asking how i should keep my devices secure/safe on a open WIFI network which is possibly malicious.
This also brings me to another related question how can i detect if a network is malicious? And what are some general network hardening tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an open Wi-Fi hotspot be considered "secure" when using a VPN connection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/can-an-open-wi-fi-hotspot-be-considered-secure-when-using-a-vpn-connection), [Is public Wi-Fi a threat nowadays?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174850/is-public-wi-fi-a-threat-nowadays), [How do I secure devices for use on conference wifi?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/163305/how-do-i-secure-devices-for-use-on-conference-wifi).

Comment: Or in short: you cannot prevent the attacker to sniff traffic and therefore you have to make sure that no sensitive data are visible in plain for the attacker: use a VPN to encrypt the traffic. Then make sure that your traffic is VPN only by denying access to your local resources from the network by using a firewall (in Windows: declare the network as public).

Comment: *"And what are some general network hardening tips."* - sorry, but this generic question makes the question too broad.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48330/37315) to [“Safe” public WiFi](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48323/safe-public-wifi). Please study the available resources  (see all the links here) first and then focus your question on the parts which are not fully answered in your opinion. Also, please keep the question focused and not too broad.